# Paperclip don't save on database

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using the following Gems:

```
'paperclip'
'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
```

I would like to save images to S3, but am unable to get them to save.

**model/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # This method associates the attribute ":avatar" with a file attachment
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '300x300>'
  }

  # Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**migration**

```
class AddAvatarToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def self.up
    add_attachment :users, :avatar
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :users, :avatar
  end
end
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Edit successfully"
      redirect_to("/users/#{@user.id}")
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :name, :email, :phone_number, :description, :college_name)
  end

end
```

Why is the image avatar not being stored in the database?
Should I add any database columns? What should I do? I would appreciate any input to help me solve this problem.

Comment: Are you getting any particular error messages when trying to update the user?

Comment: No, I'm not. Nothing error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paperclip must be configured to use S3 to store the objects (images). It will store metadata associated with these in the database, but not the images.

See [Paperclip Documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3)

You will also need to set an access policy for your S3 bucket, and define on the User model how they are to be addressed from S3.

Comment: Thank you, to answer for me!

Comment: I already set my S3 bucket in config/application.yml, however I don't define on the User model, because I don't know how to write define on the User model. What should I do

Comment: The Paperclip Gem documentation is the way to go. If you take a look at the S3 specific documentation it provides a how-to and examples: [Paperclip S3 Documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3)